# magento add validation to onestep checkout page proceed to checkout button

Tags: magento

In onestep checkout page, i created a customer payment method. Once customer select that method, i need to add some validations. That is fine. But how can i disable the button for fail validations and enable for pass validations.I tried to add some css files and do. It is as in below;

```
var path   = "mypath";
                    var style   = document.createElement( 'link' );
                    style.rel   = 'stylesheet';
                    style.type  = 'text/css';
                    style.href  = path;
                    document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[0].appendChild( style );
```

Nothing worked fine. Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which extension used for onestep checkout?. Because I want to see the checkout ajax jquery files. Your custom field validation write on that jquery file.